# Module not found running npx react-native start

Tags: android, react-native, node-modules, npx, react-native-cli

I've been wrestling with this problem of a module not being found when starting from a new or existing (ejected from expo) react-native project. After searching SO for similar problems, the errors thrown in those problems were too different for me to piece a solution from them.

Here is the command line after running the exact command:
[Module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pWYm.png)

So overall I don't know what's really going on here. Errors are being thrown in a lot of files that are abstracted from what I usually work on.

At first, I was working with an ejected expo project but stepped away from that to start a fresh react-native CLI project following the quick start guide from the docs. I followed everything with no obvious impediment until it comes to actually executing the project.

The first thing I tried was deleting the node modules and running npm install. Note: I did not delete the package-lock.json though. I also ran a command to --force delete the cache at some point. I think I did that before I tried to delete node altogether and start from the absolute latest LTS version. During the quickstart, I ran `choco install -y nodejs.install openjdk8` which installed version 16 of node and jdk8. I did already have jdk11; am I not using this kit correctly maybe?

Earlier in the day, the trace to where the error could not be found did NOT include react-native-community/cli in the path until I ran the above choco install. So it had some effect but still, nothing about the actual error changed. In the docs, it says explicitly that react-native-cli (or something like it) is packaged in with node.js so there is no need to run `npm install @react-native-commmunity/cli`. But, I've read conflicting solutions saying that, in fact, I do need it. Alas, installing @react-native-community/cli or react-native-cli globally had no effect.

At this point, I'm assuming the information/file I need is there but my computer is pointed to the wrong place. In the folder 'Work' there is no @react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js.

The .bin folder in node_modules: [react-native files in .bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcu6J.png)

To be honest I don't really understand these files but maybe something warrants changing? I can post a picture at request but I'm doubting a change is needed here.

Thank you for reading. Hopefully, I can get this up and running because my only avenue to meet my user stories is to manipulate the native android code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I feel silly but I learned something.

The reason the command didn't work was because one of my folders was named 'Routing&DeliveryApp'. Apparently, having an ampersand in the name will throw off the computer. So, it was cut off right after the ampersand searching in a folder named 'DeliveryApp' which did not exist.

Still felt like a eureka moment though. Hopefully this might help someone in the future.